# Android LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> adapter.swapCursor(data)

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I have a Fragment with ListView that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
and sometimes clicking on an list items does not trigger listener. I see clicked item highlighting but nothing more. It happens when onLoadFinished and onItemClick execute at the same time. 
Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.folder_list_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewOnItemClickListener());
}

private final class ListViewOnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("on click");
            //load new data from the database and execute update asynch
        }
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
    System.out.println("swapCursor");
}
```

Log is:

swapCursor - first time initialising

on click - click on item
swapCursor - update data
swapCursor - update data

on click - click on item 
swapCursor - update data

click on item, see background highlighting like for normal click
swapCursor - here is the problem, I have clicked on an item, but notification from previous update has discarded onClick, no any print about click to the log

on click - next time clicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found where was a problem.

Project has a database with some information and INDEX column has name "id".

According this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_content-providers--mobile-5549

> A projection is simply a list of columns to use with the adapter. The
>   ListView uses the titles and can provide an id when an item is
>   clicked. For use with an adapter, the id column must be named "_id".

Before to resolve column name problem was implemented this PROJECTION:

```
public static final String[] DEFAULT_PROJECTION = new String[] {"id _id", FolderProvider.FOLDER_COLUMN_ID,
            FolderProvider.FOLDER_COLUMN_NAME};
```

So ContentProvider and CursorAdapter works correct but some time onItemClick() was discarded.

Renaming "id" to "_id" solve the problem.

Here is good LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-properly-loading-data--mobile-5673